# Update POSIX file Apple Script syntax does not work in Mac OS 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript, osx-yosemite

I want to refresh icon for particular file/folder in Finder application. So i need to refresh selected directory.

I am trying with AppleScript:

```
NSString *source=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to update POSIX file\"%@\"",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itemPath]];
NSAppleScript *update=[[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:source];
NSDictionary *err;
[update executeAndReturnError:&err];
```

But its not working in Mac OS 10.10(Yosemite).
Please suggest any alternate of this.

Any help is appriciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

Jigs

It would help if you could add the error you are getting and the `itemPath` value to understand.

This works on 10.10.3:

```
set x to path to desktop
tell application "Finder" to update x
```

Frank